# Does parameterized query guarantee your site to be completely free from SQL INJECTION?

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How prepared statements can protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-prepared-statements-can-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks)

I read that using parameterized queries will guarantee you to be 100% safe from sql injection, but I'm not so sure. If you guys think that it's completely safe, please explain why and vice versa

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: I meant it's not an excuse to not sanitise or validate, or not use prepared statements for internal queries because you "trust the source"

Comment: @Leigh you have to state that it doesn't help against **other kinds of attacks**. Because right now your comment looks like that some "bad data" bay be used to break a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases - yes, but if you plan to build your own dynamic queries inside your parametrized query - obviously - no.